# How to implement many-to-many model in Tortoise ORM with extra field?

Tags: python, many-to-many, tortoise-orm

I'm new to Tortoise ORM and have been trying to implement a simple many-to-many model for Users/Groups/Roles

What I've tried:

1. models.py

```
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class User(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    email = fields.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = fields.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Group(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = fields.ManyToManyField("models.User", related_name="users", through="Membership")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(Model):
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User")
    group = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Group")
    role = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
```

2. main.py

```
from tortoise import Tortoise, run_async
from models import User, Group, Membership

async def init():
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db.sqlite3',
        modules={'models': ['models']}
    )
    # Generate the schema
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

    # Test
    new_user1 = await User.create(email="a@a.com",password="aa")
    new_user2 = await User.create(email="b@b.com",password="bb")
    new_user3 = await User.create(email="c@c.com",password="cc")

    new_group1 = await Group.create(name="group1")
    new_group2 = await Group.create(name="group2")
```

To create a membership link, I've tried using add() but this fails as I cannot incorporate the extra 'role' field in the association table

```
await new_group1.members.add(new_user1)
```

Results in error

```
tortoise.exceptions.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: membership.role
```

I've tried creating the memberships directly

```
await Membership.create(user_id=new_user1.id, group_id=new_group1.id, role="member")
await Membership.create(user_id=new_user2.id, group_id=new_group1.id, role="admin")
await Membership.create(user_id=new_user1.id, group_id=new_group2.id, role="member")
```

This works and I've been able to retrieve the users in each group

```
groups = await Group.all()

for i in groups:
    print(await i.members.all())
```

Which gives

```
[<User: 1>, <User: 2>]
[<User: 1>]
```

However, I don't know how to retrieve the roles of the users in the association table (Membership)

Appreciate any help with trying to implement this model

- Is possible to use add() to add a new User in the Group and specifying the role?
- How can I retrieve the roles of users in Membership when retrieving the list of users in a group?

Thanks,
Kenneth